# Netlogo: How to jump the turtle to a specific patch?

Tags: netlogo, patch

I am a beginner of the Netlogo. How can I jump the turtle with the minimum ID to a specific patch? The following is a sample program, but it will not work. I probably need your advice. Thank you.

```
ask (turtles-on patch max-pxcor 1) [
if min-one-of turtles [who] = TRUE [
  jump patch max-pxcor 0
]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want `move-to` rather than `jump`; see the NetLogo Dictionary.  I think you want this:

```
to jump-first
  ask min-one-of (turtles-on patch max-pxcor 1) [who] [
    move-to patch max-pxcor 0
  ]
end
```

I recommend reworking the NetLogo tutorials:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/tutorial1.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The tutorial has been done but I'll check it again.